# How to display a list of points using dbclick in react-leaflet v.3.x?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm very new to react and what I want to do is basically just display a set of points on the map. I have a custom component called CovidPoints which basically just renders a Marker on the map. Currently I have a function component that detects when a double click happens and then creates a point at the mouse position. Now what happens is that the point is created only after the first double click. I want to be able to double click many times and create points each time. For this I think I need to append the return of the Location Marker function to a points array prop but I'm not sure how to do this.

Location Marker.js:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import {useMapEvents, Marker, Popup} from 'react-leaflet';
import CovidPoint from './CovidPoint';

function LocationMarker() {
    const [points, setPoints] = useState(null)
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)
    const map = useMapEvents({
        dblclick(ev) {
            console.log("double clicked");
            const coord = map.mouseEventToLatLng(ev.originalEvent);
            setPosition(coord);
        },
    })
    
    return position === null ? null : (
      <CovidPoint position={position}></CovidPoint>
    )
  }

  export default LocationMarker;
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMapEvents, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import CovidPoint from './CovidPoint';
import LocationMarker from './LocationMarker';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      map: null,
      points: []
    }
  }

  changePos = (pos, zoom) => {
    const {map} = this.state;
    if (map) map.flyTo(pos, zoom);
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <ChakraProvider resetCSS = {false}>
        <div className = "App">
          <div id="title">
            <h1>
              CovidStopSpots
            </h1>
              <p>A responsive tracker for Covid-19.</p>          
          </div>
          <div id="map">
            <MapContainer id = "1" center={[43.653226, -79.3831843]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} whenCreated={map => this.setState({ map })}>
              <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              />
             <CovidPoint position={[43.653226, -79.3831843]} name="point1" information="random point"></CovidPoint>
             <CovidPoint position={[50.653226, -79.3831843]} name="point2" information="random point"></CovidPoint>
             <LocationMarker></LocationMarker>
            </MapContainer>
            <div id="searchbar">
            <SearchBar changePos = {this.changePos}></SearchBar>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </ChakraProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

CovidPoint.js:

```
import './SearchBar.css';
import * as React from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker } from 'react-leaflet';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

class CovidPoint extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      positon: this.props.position,
      name: this.props.name,
      information: this.props.information,
    }
  }
  

  render () {
    const covidIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Redpoint.svg/768px-Redpoint.svg.png',
  
      iconSize:     [30, 30], // size of the icon
      iconAnchor:   [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
      popupAnchor:  [0, 0] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
  });

    return (
    <div>
      <Marker position={this.state.positon} icon={covidIcon}>
        <Popup>
          Name: {this.state.name} <br />
          Case Status: {this.state.information}
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CovidPoint;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current implementation you don't pass name and information props on your CovidPoint comp via `LocationMarker`.

To display a list of points you need to have an array of `latlngs` as you implied on the question description. Therefor your LocationMarker comp should look like this:

```
function LocationMarker() {
  const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);

  useMapEvents({
    dblclick(ev) {
      console.log("double clicked");
      const { lat, lng } = ev.latlng;
      const newPositions = [...positions];
      newPositions.push([lat, lng]);
      setPositions(newPositions);
    }
  });

  return <CovidPoint positions={positions}></CovidPoint>;
}
```

You take latlng object that contains the coordinates of the clicked place and then you add them to your positions array. Should be plural because there are going to be many places and not one.

On your CovidPoint loop over the positions to render the points. You do not need to assign positions to a state variable unless you want to manipulate it further as a local var:

```
<div>
     {this.props.positions.length > 0 &&
       this.props.positions.map((position, index) => (
         <Marker position={position} icon={covidIcon} key={index}>
           {/* <Popup>
           Name: {this.state.name} <br />
           Case Status: {this.state.information}
         </Popup> */}
        </Marker>
     ))}
</div>
```

Then you need to change this part

```
 {/* <Popup>
      Name: {this.state.name} <br />
      Case Status: {this.state.information}
 </Popup> */}
```

because it does not get name and information as props from LocationMarker comp

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-display-a-list-of-points-using-dbclick-in-react-leaflet-v3x-v2kf2?file=/src/CovidPoint.jsx)

Comment: Thanks. Coming from python and Java, this seems really unfamiliar and a strange workflow for me. Just wondering, how does the code work in the CovidPoints <div>, wouldn't you need an if statement, I don't understan the syntax of this.position.length > 0 && (then do this), is that the same as if (this.position.length) > 0 {then do this} in java? Also where does the index prop come from?

Comment: Javascript has a lot of differences comparing to python and Java, indeed. In Javascript if an expression evaluates to `true` when using with `&&` operator it returns the variable after `&&` operator. So when `this.props.position.length > 0` is `truthy` it will return the jsx code, the Markers in this case. It is like a shortcut if you were doing `if (expression) return jsx code ` as you mentioned.